# GradientLayer doesn't fill UIButton bounds horizontally

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uibutton

I created a custom UIButton with a gradient layer. When I test the app on my iPhone, the button is filled with the gradient layer vertically, however the gradient layer only fills the button 3/4 of the way horizontally. It still triggers input events on the uncolored part of the button, so I know that the size of the button is correct, however I can't seem to figure out how to get the GradientLayer to fill the button completely.

Here's the source to my custom UIButton:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let topColor    = UIColor(red: (40/255.0), green: (168/255.0), blue: (94/255.0), alpha: 1)
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: (134/255.0), blue: (55/255.0), alpha: 1)

    let gradientColors: [CGColor]  = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
    let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    gradientLayer.colors        = gradientColors
    gradientLayer.locations     = gradientLocations
    gradientLayer.frame         = self.bounds
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius  = 5.0

    self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
```

Here's an image of the button when I run the app on my iPhone 6:
[image: GradientLayer only fills 3/4 of button horizontally]

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Auto Layout? The button is probably being resized after you set the gradient layer frame to a larger frame.

You can try to set the layer frame again in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Answer (score 2):

Setting the layer frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews works, but here he is inside the view, so it should go in

```
func layout()
```

(after the call to super).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers guys. Helped me get on the right track. I resize the layer in layoutSubviews(), here's the code

```
let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let topColor    = UIColor(red: (40/255.0), green: (168/255.0), blue: (94/255.0), alpha: 1)
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: (134/255.0), blue: (55/255.0), alpha: 1)

    let gradientColors: [CGColor]  = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
    let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]

    gradientLayer.colors        = gradientColors
    gradientLayer.locations     = gradientLocations
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius  = 5.0

    self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews();

    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
}
```